# How do I configure rsyslog on Ubuntu 14.04 to use ISO8601 timestamps?

Tags: ubuntu, syslog, rsyslog

In a file in /etc/rsyslog.d/ I have the following:

```
local3.*        /var/log/mylog.log
```

When I log to this facility, records have timestamps which look like this:

```
Apr 27 21:12:20 hostname msg
```

How do I set things up so that they look like this instead?

```
2014-04-27T21:12:20 hostname msg
```

Comment: What research have you done on your own? Rsyslog ships with this functionality, and a simple google search returned results with implementation instructions within the first few links.

Comment: If you have an answer please share it. I did a google search which suggested that ISO8601 was the default timestamp format,  but it is clearly not on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @EEAA, this question is now the top google search result for "rsyslog ubuntu iso8601 timestamps" and none of the other top 10 address this specific question which suggests to me that it was not a wholly terrible question to ask.

Comment: This site is supposed to be the authoritative source for answers. *Most* of the content here can be found via Google search, but then the site would be lacking all of the content which drives page views.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be achieved by commenting out the following line in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` as the comment suggests:

```
#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
```

Log format now looks like this:

```
2014-04-29T20:41:36.366613+01:00 hostname msg
```

Comment: Don't forget to restart rsyslog after this (e.g. ```/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart```)

Comment: On later Ubuntu versions with systemd (introduced in 13.04, default in 15.04+), you can run `systemctl restart rsyslog` as root or using sudo. `systemctl status rsyslog` will show you status info, including how long it's been running.